# How to change DialogFragment header background color and bottom line color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am trying to customise some styling of a DialogFragment.

I have changed the color of the title with:

```
TextView title = (TextView)getDialog().findViewById( android.R.id.title );
title.setTextColor( getResources().getColor( R.color.base_app_color ) );
```

Now what I do need is to change the background color of the header and the bottom line color as well.

Does anyone know which are those android.R.id.??? or how I could archive it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use a theme for this?

Comment: You could be right, but I do not know which are those items names, do you? Also I could use a different layout, but I am keen if it's possible just to change those colours. Thanks you @Gumbo

Comment: I (maybe) found the ID of the divider: `android.R.id.titleDivider` let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but that id does not exist android.R.id.titleDivider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually find the divider after the dialog has been created:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

// Set title divider color
int titleDividerId = getResources().getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
View titleDivider = dialog.findViewById(titleDividerId);
if (titleDivider != null)
    titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_purple));
```

Customising the background of the header is slightly more complex... You need to define in your theme an `alertDialogStyle` defining how you draw each area of the dialog. For example:

```
<style name="Theme.Yours" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    ...
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog_Yours</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog_Yours">
    <item name="android:fullDark">...</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">...</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">...</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">...</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">...</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">...</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">...</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">...</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">...</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">...</item>
</style>
```

Those areas can be colors or drawables, and to understand what they are, I redirect you to [a blog post I wrote on the subject](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/) (part 5), explaining how you can theme everything.

Answer (score 3):

If the default dialogs don't meet your needs, you are best off providing your own custom layout. You can then make it look exactly as you want in XML.
This is well explained in the docs (see [Creating a Custom Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout))